# Rainfall data, observations for meteo stations with coordinates. How to take off NA?

Tags: r, na

I am trying to get together stations and observations, these are two different files at my desktop. But problem is that when I have not observation (it was not raining), there appears NA in table. See my code:

```
together<-cbind(stationdata,observations)

together

for (i in 1:dim(observation)[2]) {

    indx<-match(names(observation[i],row.names(together))
    if (!is.na(indx)) {
        together[indx,3]<-as.numeric(as.character(observation[1,i])) 
    }
}
```

I get a table like this:

```
                  latitude  longitude          rainfall
 stat1             46.67541  22.50364          0.1
 stat2             47.14956  24.86033           NA
 stat3             46.23182  26.00166           NA
 stat4             46.64258  25.12821          0.0
 stat5             47.30063  24.41219          0.0
```

Is there some function, which will replace NA with 0 in that case?

Solved:
The solution for my question is:

together$rainfall[is.na(together$rainfall)] <- 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `is.na()` to find the indexes with `NA` values in `rainfall` then assign `0` to `rainfall` instead:

```
together$rainfall[is.na(together$rainfall)] <- 0
```

Comment: A little explanation of the code would be good for better understanding.

Comment: @DanielLisik good point. but this question is asked so often i didn't have the energy to explain it. If you want to post an answer with a better description, i'd be happy to up-vote it.

Comment: Daniel Lisik, In this code I put together stations and observations data from 2 different files, I do that by comparing rownames from 1 file "together" (In this file is information about meteo stations and one column is blank for observations) and column names from file "observation". MrFlick have already answered my question.